# inject one service into another and have access to the injected services members angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

everything I'm reading here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action makes this seem like it should be possible, but I get this error when trying to call a method on my injected service from another service:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined
>       at CatchSubscriber.handleError [as selector] (project.service.ts:30)
>       at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
>       at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:56)
>       at TapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>       at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>       at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>       at FilterSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>       at FilterSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:7)
>       at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:14)

Here is my `ProjectService` which is injecting my `UserService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthHeader } from '../../Shared/Helpers/AuthHeader';
import { UserService } from '../../User/Services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {

  }
  private projectsApiEndPointRoot = '/api/ProjectApi/';
  test(): Observable<number> {
    return <Observable<number>>this.http.get<number>(this.projectsApiEndPointRoot + "getimages/8", { headers: AuthHeader.getAuthHeader() }).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      if (err.status == 401 || err.status == 403) {
        console.log(this.userService.isLoggedIn());
      }
      else {
        errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
      }
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

The `UserService` just has a method that should return boolean whether or not the user is logged in.  I use that same method on several components with success, but it's not working when trying to call it from this other service.

Is this not possible to do?

EDIT: adding bits of `UserService` for demonstration:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EmailModel } from '../Models/EmailModel';
import { ILoginRequest } from '../Interfaces/ILoginRequest';
import { ILoginResponse } from '../Interfaces/ILoginResponse';
import { IRegistrationRequest } from '../Interfaces/IRegistrationRequest';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  private usersApiEndPointRoot = 'api/UserApi/';

  private loggedIn = false;
  ...

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }


  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. It certainly is possible. Can you post the code of UserService as well?

Comment: is userService undefined if you do a console.log(this.userService) in the constructor as well?

Comment: try to change the method signature: `private handleError = (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {...}` Maybe it has something to do with scope

Comment: yes, `UserService` is undefined.  See my edit where I've added the important parts of it to my OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the function on the user service.  When it is called it the value of `this` will be the window.

Instead of passing the function to the `catchError` function, use a lambda function so that this will be preserved.  Make following change to the `test()` method and your problem will be solved:

```
test(): Observable<number> {
  return <Observable<number>>this.http.get<number>(this.projectsApiEndPointRoot + 
      "getimages/8", { headers: AuthHeader.getAuthHeader() }).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(data)),
    catchError(err => this.handleError(err)) // <--
  );
}
```

Comment: That's true. You can use `catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))` as well

Comment: this resolved it for me.  I hate when I don't fully understand stuff so would you mind elaborating just a bit more?  Why does passing `catchError()` an inline function that calls `handleError()` preserve my instance of `UserService`?

Comment: When you just pass the reference to the method, that method has no concept what the value of `this` should be.  Whatever `this` is on the current stack that is what is used.  Here's a demonstration (you need to view your console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-egphws

Comment: @DanielGimenez that is a super helpful demonstration.  Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use arrow functions in catchError to be able to use the class context this.

```
catchError((err) => this.handleError(err))
```

Otherwise the context is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna put my comment as an answer as well, since it is a little bit different from the other answers.

Change the signature of your method like this

`private handleError = (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {...}`

Then you can keep the `catchError(this.handleError)` as it is if you want to.